# OpenCL Sanitize Function Inputs

Tags: opencl

Some OpenCL functions crash the kernel if any of their arguments are non-standard floats like `NAN` or `INFINITY`.  I am trying to stop these crashes from occurring by wrapping my arguments to remove bad values.

Here are three of my attempts to create argument sanitizers:

- `clean_arg = clamp(dirty_arg, 1, 10000);` Crashes
- `clean_arg = convert_float(convert_int(dirty_arg));` Hacky
- `clean_arg = isnan(dirty_arg) ? 1 : dirty_arg;` Verbose

Is there a better way to detect and remove undesirable floating-point values?

Comment: Are you using some compiler flags that ignores the NaN numbers and their effects? I guess that if not, then this is a compiler bug.

Comment: If I turn off those flags, won't the compiler just throw more warnings, and I'll have to deal with dirty arguments on the host side?

Comment: I'm writing a kernel-code generator, so just writing my kernel well is not an option.

Comment: NAN and INFINITY are standard floating point numbers defined in the IEEE 754 standard.  Support for INFINITY and NAN has been a requirement in OpenCL since 1.0.  Which OpenCL functions are crashing and on which hardware have you observed this behaviour?  What compiler options do you use when building the kernel?